# Gradle ignores internal nexus repository

Tags: java, linux, gradle

I have very simple java project, and I'm using gradle to build it.
And I have Linux RedHat server (without access to internet) but this server has access to internal nexus repository where all required dependencies present.

This is `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://nexus.com.mysite/nexus/content/repositories/mirror/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb' version '1.3.5' // this is 14 line
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://nexus.com.mysite/nexus/content/repositories/mirror/" }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://nexus.com.mysite/nexus/content/repositories/mirror/" }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://nexus.com.mysite/nexus/content/repositories/mirror/" }
    }
}

allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://nexus.com.mysite/nexus/content/repositories/mirror/" }
        }
    }
}
```

Settings file `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'api'

project(":api").name = "api"
```

And this project has 1 submodule `api` filder.
api `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven { url "https://nexus.com.mysite/nexus/content/repositories/mirror/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.TestApplication'
}
```

On my linux server I have:
- java 8
- gradle 4.5.1
- mvn 3.5.6

When I'm running `gradle clean` inside root folder of my project, after 5-10 mins I'm receiving error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/my-proj/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb', version: '1.3.5'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb:com.github.jacobono.jaxb.gradle.plugin:1.3.5')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10m 3s
```

And for some reason in this error there is no information about my nexus repository...I assuming that it even haven't tried this repository. And the question is why...?

I would be very happy of any help...maybe I made mistake in build.gradle file somewhere...

p.s. on my local pc(I have access to internet and to this repository everything works file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins by default resolved from Gradle Plugin Portal. If you want to resolve them from different sources, You should add configuration to settings.gradle file.

Example:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url '../maven-repo'
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        ivy {
            url '../ivy-repo'
        }
    }
}
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories) for details.